# Can teamcity fail a build if a suitable dependency is not found?

Tags: teamcity, pipeline, build-chain

In TeamCity I have setup a build chain where each environment is dependent upon the builds in the previous environment must be suitable and successful.

However, I would like to fail the build if a suitable build dependency is not found.

The scenario includes a stage gate where a different team is responsible for deployment to production.  If they try to deploy a build that doesn't have a suitable dependency, you can configure tc to build or not build the dependency.  I would like the build to fail indicating the dependency does not exist.

Comment: Here is an option in TeamCity snapshot dependency configuration:
"On failed dependency"/"On failed to start/canceled dependency". You can select the value: "Make build failed ti start". Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can use [Snapshot dependencies](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Snapshot+Dependencies)  in this scenario.

According to the Teamcity9 documentation for `On failed dependency/ 
On failed to start/canceled dependency`, you can do any of the following

- Run build, but add problem: the dependent build will be run and the problem will be added to it, changing its status to failed (if problem was not muted earlier)
- Run build, but do not add problem: the dependent build will be run and no problems will be added
- **Make build failed to start: the dependent build will not run and will be marked as "Failed to start"**
- Cancel build: the dependent build will not run and will be marked as "Canceled".
  Make build failed to start: the dependent build will not run and will be marked as "Failed to start"
  Cancel build: the dependent build will not run and will be marked as "Canceled".

The **3rd option** is what you are looking for